# error: [Dagger/DependencyCycle] Found a dependency cycle error after using ActivityRetainedScoped

Tags: java, android, android-room, dagger-2, dagger-hilt

I am working on app that uses MVVM, Room and dagger hilt, I have implemented first part that handle server response, remote DataSource, viewmodel and all this stuff, and it's worked fine, but after I implemented the database module, I got this error when I tried to build

```
public abstract static class SingletonC implements BaseApplication_GeneratedInjector,
                         ^
      com.test.dummyappv3.data.database.ItemDAO is injected at
          com.test.dummyappv3.di.DatabaseModule.provideDao(itemDAO)
      com.test.dummyappv3.data.database.ItemDAO is injected at
          com.test.dummyappv3.data.LocalDataSource(itemDAO)
      com.test.dummyappv3.data.LocalDataSource is injected at
          com.test.dummyappv3.data.Repository(�, localDataSource)
      com.test.dummyappv3.data.Repository is injected at
          com.test.dummyappv3.viewmodels.PostViewModel(repository)
      com.test.dummyappv3.viewmodels.PostViewModel is injected at
          com.test.dummyappv3.viewmodels.PostViewModel_HiltModules.BindsModule.binds(vm)
      @dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.HiltViewModelMap java.util.Map<java.lang.String,javax.inject.Provider<androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel>> is requested at
          dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.HiltViewModelFactory.ViewModelFactoriesEntryPoint.getHiltViewModelMap() [com.test.dummyappv3.BaseApplication_HiltComponents.SingletonC ? com.test.dummyappv3.BaseApplication_HiltComponents.ActivityRetainedC ? com.test.dummyappv3.BaseApplication_HiltComponents.ViewModelC]
```

and I think it's related with `ActivityRetainedScoped` in Repository Class

```
@ActivityRetainedScoped
public class Repository {

    public RemoteDataSource remoteDataSource;
    public LocalDataSource localDataSource;

    @Inject
    public Repository(RemoteDataSource remoteDataSource, LocalDataSource localDataSource) {
        this.remoteDataSource = remoteDataSource;
        this.localDataSource = localDataSource;
    }
}
```

**DatabaseModule**

```
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent.class)
@Module
public class DatabaseModule {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    public static ItemsDatabase provideDatabase(@ApplicationContext Context context){
        return Room.databaseBuilder(context,ItemsDatabase.class,"items_database")
                .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                .build();

    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    public static ItemDAO provideDao(ItemDAO itemDAO){
        return itemDAO;
    }
}
```

**RemoteDataSource**

```
    private final PostAPIService postAPIService;


    @Inject
    public RemoteDataSource(PostAPIService postAPIService) {
        this.postAPIService = postAPIService;
    }

    public Observable<PostList> getPostList(String URL) {
        return postAPIService.getPostList(URL);
    }

    public Observable<PostList> getPostListByLabel(String URL) {
        return postAPIService.getPostListByLabel(URL);
    }

}
```

LocalDataSource

```
public class LocalDataSource {

    private final ItemDAO itemDAO;

    @Inject
    public LocalDataSource(ItemDAO itemDAO) {
        this.itemDAO = itemDAO;
    }

    public Completable insertItem(Item item){
        return itemDAO.insert(item);
    }

    public Flowable<List<Item>> getAlItems(){
        return itemDAO.getAlItems();
    }

}
```

and finally the viewmodel

```
@HiltViewModel
public class PostViewModel extends ViewModel {

    public static final String TAG = "PostViewModel";


    private Repository repository = null;
    public MutableLiveData<PostList> postListMutableLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();
    public MutableLiveData<String> finalURL = new MutableLiveData<>();
    public MutableLiveData<String> token = new MutableLiveData<>();
    public MutableLiveData<String> label = new MutableLiveData<>();

    public MutableLiveData<Boolean> ifAnythingWrongHappened = new MutableLiveData<>();

    @Inject
    public PostViewModel(Repository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    public final LiveData<List<Item>> getAllPostsFromDB
            = LiveDataReactiveStreams.fromPublisher(repository.localDataSource.getAlItems());

    @SuppressLint("CheckResult")
    public void getPosts() {
        ifAnythingWrongHappened.setValue(false);
        Log.e(TAG, finalURL.getValue());

        repository.remoteDataSource.getPostList(finalURL.getValue())
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Observer<PostList>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSubscribe(@io.reactivex.rxjava3.annotations.NonNull Disposable d) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(@io.reactivex.rxjava3.annotations.NonNull PostList postList) {
                        Log.e(TAG, postList.getNextPageToken());
                        token.setValue(postList.getNextPageToken());
                        postListMutableLiveData.setValue(postList);
                        for (int i = 0; i < postList.getItems().size(); i++) {
                            repository.localDataSource.insertItem(postList.getItems().get(i))
                                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
                                    .subscribe(new CompletableObserver() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onSubscribe(@io.reactivex.rxjava3.annotations.NonNull Disposable d) {

                                        }

                                        @Override
                                        public void onComplete() {

                                        }

                                        @Override
                                        public void onError(@io.reactivex.rxjava3.annotations.NonNull Throwable e) {
                                            Log.e(TAG, "onError: "+e.getMessage() );
                                            ifAnythingWrongHappened.setValue(true);
                                        }
                                    });
                        }
                        finalURL.setValue(finalURL.getValue() + "&pageToken=" + token.getValue());

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(@io.reactivex.rxjava3.annotations.NonNull Throwable e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage() + e.getCause());
                        ifAnythingWrongHappened.setValue(true);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete() {

                    }
                });
}
```

I tried to delete this `@ActivityRetainedScoped` and `@ApplicationContext` but the same error also I tried the `@ViewModelScoped` in the viewmodel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```java
    @Singleton
    @Provides
    public static ItemDAO provideDao(ItemDAO itemDAO){
        return itemDAO;
    }
```

This is the circular dependency.  The important part of that error trace to look at is everything from the first entry (`ItemDAO`) up to and excluding the second appearance of that same class.  The rest of the error message is showing one use of `ItemDAO` in the dependency graph, since Dagger only validates reachable dependencies.

I assume you intended to do something like this instead:

```java
    @Singleton
    @Provides
    public static ItemDAO provideDao(ItemsDatabase database){
        return database.itemDAO();
    }
```

Comment: Oh! this is silly mistake, I saw it in the lesson but I changed it from database to itemDao, I wasn't know it's will make different, anyway thanks for this notice, I was not understand to read dagger errors :)

Comment: What can I do without StackOverflow?? I just exactly the same error. Thx @DrMido for saving the day.